# How do you write a tabular function in Kusto taking a mix of tabular and scalar arguments so you can reuse and share it across the organization?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring, kql

I have been googling and fiddling around this for a couple of days now and have been unable to find the answer.

What I am trying to achieve is to count the number of servers running an azure function across a time period in a specific time bucket, I want my organization to reuse this query as a tabular function that receives **the app insights requests table** associated with whatever resource we are monitoring as well as **the time bucket** used to bin the data, **the start date** and **the end date** of the query.

The basic signature should be as follows in my understanding:

```
let TotalServerCount = (T:(timestamp:datetime, customDimensions:dynamic, instanceId:guid), 
                          binBucket:timespan = 2m, startDate:datetime, endDate:datetime)
{
    T
    | "tabular expression"
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of this and always get the same error: **Body of the callable expression cannot be empty**

I have followed guidelines from the following links:

1. [Scalar data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/)
2. [User defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions)
3. [Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/queries)

here is the complete function code:

```
let TotalServerCount = (T:(timestamp:datetime, customDimensions:dynamic, instanceId:guid), 
                           binBucket:timespan = 2m, startDate:datetime, endDate:datetime)
{
    T
    | extend instanceId = toguid(customDimensions.HostInstanceId)
    | where timestamp >= startDate and timestamp <= endDate
    | summarize instanceIdCount=dcount(instanceId) by bin(timestamp, binBucket)
    | union (
        range x from 1 to 1 step 1
            | mvexpand timestamp=range(startDate, endDate, binBucket) to typeof(datetime) 
            | extend instanceIdCount=0
            | project timestamp, instanceIdCount
    )
    | order by timestamp asc
    | summarize instanceIdCount=sum(instanceIdCount) by bin(timestamp, binBucket)
    | render timechart
};
```

Which I would then call in a separate query window like so:

```
TotalServerCount(requests, 2m, ago(30d), now())
```

As per the examples provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions):

> **A tabular function:**
>
> - Is a function with no inputs, or at least one tabular input, and produces a tabular output
> - Can be used wherever a tabular expression is allowed
>
> **Note**
>
> All tabular parameters must appear before scalar parameters.
>
> Example of a tabular function that uses a tabular input and a scalar
>   input:

```
let MyFilter = (T:(x:long), v:long) {
  T | where x >= v 
};
MyFilter((range x from 1 to 10 step 1), 9)
```

Does anyone know what I am misunderstanding here? Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

**Note:** There is a known issue with the above query where the 0 server count is not properly rendendered in the line chart, that is however not relevant for this question. My problem is specifically focused on the reusability of the query as a function for multiple resources.

**Edit:**
As per [Yoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7861807/yoni-leibowitz)'s comment below, here is a couple of examples simple examples.

**One that works:**

```
let T = range x from todatetime("04/01/2020 00:00:00 AM") to now() step 1d;
T 
| where x >= ago(5d)
```

**One that doesn't:**

```
let T = range x from todatetime("04/01/2020 00:00:00 AM") to now() step 1d;
let TotalServerCount = (T:(x:datetime), v:datetime) {
  T | where x >= v 
};
TotalServerCount(T, ago(5d))
```

You can view the failed execution of the above example [here](https://ibb.co/sHQsgmS).

**Failed Request ID:** 9d8649f4-58e3-4ade-a698-ee0856961ac0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was an Azure issue within the Azure portal itself.

As of today 15/05/2020, **the same code I posted in this question is working fine against Application Insights** and the original issue is still being investigated by Microsoft Support.

I would fell safe in venturing the guess that there was a bug in the azure portal around shared functions since with the latest release of the portal the same code now work and my previously saved query functions have been deleted from my account auto-magically.

Given that this is now working with no changes from my end I will answer my own question and mark it as closed.

Answer (score 0):

`Body of the callable expression cannot be empty` is the message of the error returned when, well, the body of the callable expression is empty. e.g. in this example:

```
let F = (a:string) { }; // <-- there's nothing in the curly braces
F("hello world")
```

could you perhaps provide a relevant-but-minimal example of a query that is both runnable (doesn't require access to your cluster/database), but results with the error you're seeing, and you don't understand why?

e.g.

```
let T = datatable(a:string)
[
    "hello", "world", "foo", "bar", "3"
]
;
let F = (T:(a:string), x:string) 
{
    T
    | project a = tolong(a)
    | where isnotnull(a)
    | join (range y from 1 to 4 step 1)
      on $left.a == $right.y
}
;
F(T, 3)
```

Comment: I added the extra examples as requested, hope it makes it simpler ;)

Comment: thanks. the example you included under "**One that doesn't**" actually does work (at least on my ADX/Kusto cluster). can you perhaps explain why it doesn't work? e.g. include the error message, and client request ID for the failed execution?

Comment: Well I am running this in an Azure Application Insights Logs through the Azure portal directly, albeit naively my expectation would be it had the same behavior in both cases.

Regardless I uploaded a screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/sHQsgmS) of the failed execution, and the generated **Request ID** (9d8649f4-58e3-4ade-a698-ee0856961ac0) obtained from the portal.

Hopefully that makes it clearer.

**note:** Thank you for your time on this, I am really struggling to understand what is happening, even more so now that you told me it is working for you. I might have to raise a support ticket

Comment: i don't have access to any App Insights resources, so you may want to go ahead with opening a support ticket to get this sorted out